# Preventing copilot suggestions when "normal" suggestions are present

Tags: neovim, autocompletion

Since my last update of my plugins, copilot now gets in a fight with CoC trying to complete. The result is that I can't use tab to select the first CoC suggestion, since it will apply the copilot suggestion.

Previously, the behavior was that whenever there was a "normal" autocomplete suggestion, tab would do that one instead of the Copilot on. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to change the "priority"? I'd also just be interested in references to documentation which might be relevant.